# How to avoid sed outputting new line / carriage return?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I'm decomposing a single line multiple times, recomposing it after each step, but each command adds a new line to the output.

Basically, these are the commands:

```
h
s#(^.*?)(\[\{.*$)#\1#p
g
s#(^.*?)(\[\{.*?\}\])(.*)$#echo \2 | jq --sort-keys --compact-output#ep
g
s#(^.*?\}\])(.*)$#\2#p
z
```

But the original line results in three lines after sed, because each `/p` adds a newline after the content: How can I avoid that? One line from input should result in one line in the ouput.

Instead of `/p`, I also tried writing the `s` commands result to file with `/w filename` flag, then read it with `r filename` command, but the file content is added straight to the output, giving the same result.

And `/p` is because I tried adding the -n command line parameter to sed.

To add a bit of context: I'm parsing logs HTTP POST requests, which are made of a timestamp, the request URI, the request JSON body and the request headers and I'm trying to use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to uniformly order that JSON properties.

Comment: You may want to post the actual JSON document that you're working with and an explanation of the changes that you want to make to this document.  Using `sed` is not adequate for parsing or modifying JSON.

Comment: @Kusalananda Agreed, but I think that makes for a different question (and I'll post another one); here I'm asking whether there's a way to tell `sed` not to automatically add a newline when writing output - that is instead what is being done, as stated [in the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Execution-Cycle.html#Execution-Cycle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to obtain the result I wanted, with the following script:

```
h
# Extract the first part of the input line and store it as-is
s#(^.*?)(\[\{.*$)#\1#
H
g
# (1)
s#$(\n|.)*\'##m
# Extract the second part of the input line and process it with an external command
s#(^.*?)(\[\{.*?\}\])(.*)$#echo \2 | jq --sort-keys --compact-output#e
H
g
# (1)
s#$(\n|.)*\'##m
# Extract the third (and final) part of the input line and store it as-is
s#(^.*?\}\])(.*)$#\2#m
H
g
# (2) 
s#^.*$\n##m
# (3)
s#\n##mg
```

I basically keep the original input in the *hold space*, by initially copying it (with `h`), then accumulating partial processing results appending them to the *hold space* (with `H`). Thus, when I replace the *pattern space* with the *hold space* (with `g`) I need to remove those extra components (with command (1)).

At the end of the processing, I remove the first line - that is the original input line - (with command (2)) and remove all the newlines added by previous usage of `H` commands (with command (3)), effectively recomposing a single line before printing the *pattern space* to output.

Note: I soon discovered that the shell command invocation is a real blocker, it slows down processing a single file (the processing does several steps other thatn this with `sed`) from a couple of minutes to too much to wait.

Comment: What version of `sed` are you  using? Bcoz the non-greedy regex `.*?` is not available in GNU sed. Only superseded `ssed` maybe has this feature.

Comment: @guest_7 Version 4.2.1 from [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) (I'm on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, you can use `tr -d '\n'` to remove newlines, including the ones introduced by `sed`.

Comment: Thanks. I hoped there was a way to tell `sed` not to output the newline tough, to save an additional parsing / processing step of the whole file.

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention: I need to merge (remove newlines) from groups of three rows, not join them all. One row from the input file is split into three (by the three `s` steps), I need to join them back in one.

Comment: @watery Please edit your question to include these details. Also, please provide a (possibly anonymized) example of the input to be processed, along with the desired result of your `sed` operations.